# Problem with setting UIImageView to UIImage from camera (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, camera

Content: 
I stored the image from the iPhone's camera into a UIImage *storedImage defined in ClassA.

In ClassB (subClass of ClassA) I have a UIImageView *imageView which I proceeded to set

```
UIImageView.image = storedImage
```

since ClassB has access to ClassA's objects.

Problem: 
Stored image does not show when ClassB's nib runs and I just can't figure out why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: give some more code. How do you set storedImage ? The code `UIImageView.image = storedImage` is wrong and can't work. Where do you set .image ? Give more details.

Answer (score 0):

We need more source code. have you initialized the UIImageView?

Have you tried using setImage property of UIImageView ?

Also more basically, have you added the UIImageView view to the current view?